# Storing a string in Azure blob storage and getting a reference to the blob with C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

guys,

I've got code making an API call, getting JSON back, parsing it and storing it in an SQL table. Now I'd like to take that JSON and also save it in Azure blob storage, then save a reference to it in the SQL table as a separate field.

So far, I've got this:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mydata");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(dataString);
blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(resultContent);
```

What can I save as the reference string, for future retrieval of the blob? Is it blockBlob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every blob will have a uri like:

```
https://<yourstorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname
```

This is what you would store in your database. You can even use this uri to provide a direct link, within your app, to an end-user directly (e.g. as a link in a web page). Note: for the direct-link to work externally (e.g. without storage account credentials), the container would need to be public, or you'd need to create a Shared Access Signature to allow for temporary public access, if it's in a private container.

Arguably, you can store just the container/blob name, but then, if you have multiple storage accounts, you'll need to know which one you stored it in.

Comment: So in the above case, the URI would be `https://<yourstorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blockBlob`?

Comment: if the blob name is `blockBlob` then yes. The type of blob is not embedded in the uri. If the json file is `mydata.json` then it would end in `/containername/mydata.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be changed like following:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("datastring.json");
```

You can later retrieve this with the same name i.e. datastring.json, and you can save the same blob name in your database.